# Why are global elements so special?

Tags: category-theory

I'm starting to study category theory and I don't understand these remarks in this [book](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Category_Theory.html?id=-MCJ6x2lC7oC&redir_esc=y):

[image]

I have the following questions:

1. Why does we study the global elements $x:1\to M$, since as we see in example 2, there are categories which doesn't work so well with global elements? so, why are they special to make us care about it?
2. I need help to prove 3, I can't avoid to think the morphisms as functions, I don't know how to prove it in a general category.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For 3, take $D = C$, $x = id_C$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi yes, but how about the converse?

Comment: What do you mean "the converse"?

Comment: The statement is: "In any category **C** and for any arrows $f,g:C\to C'$, we always have $f=g$ iff for all $x:D\to C$, it holds that $fx=gx$" So your comment seems to be addressed to $\leftarrow$ part of this statement.

Comment: Well if $f = g$ then of course $fx = gx$, whatever $x$ is...

Answer (score 7):

The most important (and in fact, motivating) example is the category of sheaves on a space $X$. Here a global element is the same as a global section (this also explains the name). Of course, not every sheaf is defined via its global sections, but they are definitely interesting. In fact, one of the most important theorems in a first course on algebraic geometry is Riemann-Roch, which just counts (the dimension of) global sections of a given divisor on a curve.

The whole point of generalized elements is that they are an adequate replacement of global elements. They are more general and also more powerful: Every object is determined via its generalized elements - this is the Yoneda Lemma. In 3., simply take $x=\mathrm{id}$ (this is the "universal" generalized element).

When you cannot think about categories without thinking about sets and functions, you should consult a list of abstract categories (path category of a graph, homotopy category, relation category, groups as categories, partial orders as categories, etc.).

Comment: Can I say only with global elements we have for example the following identification: $X\cong Hom_{Sets}(1,X)$? I'm trying to find a more simple motivation.

Comment: When I say that I can't think without thinking about sets, I was strictly speaking in this question in particular. I don't know how to prove two morphisms are equal, I know how prove it just in concrete categories.

Comment: $X \cong \hom_{\mathrm{Set}}(1, X)$ doesn't make sense unless $X$ is a set.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi yes, I know.